# Android Fragment Activity

Tags: android-fragments

Is it possible to add one Fragment Activity inside anothe fragment Activity in Android ? is there any example for this?

Thanks 
Rahul

Comment: Sorry for that Mitch but now onwords i will take care of these things Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t think so. FragmentActivity is equivalent to Activity, the diferrence is that this object can contain fragments. The idea is that you can add more than one fragment inside a fragmentActivity, you should be able to do whatever you want on this way.